# Optimize List of Relational Operators to Minimum Set

Tags: algorithm, comparator

Would it be possible to create an algorithm to find the minimal set of relational operators given an input list of relational operators? I am not sure if I am using the proper mathematical nomenclature for the problem.

For instance, if the list of operators:

```
[x > 1, x > 3], minimal set: [x > 1]
[x < 1, x > 3], minimal set: [x < 1, x > 3]
[x > 1, x < 2], minimal set: undefined
```

With of course, the list being arbitrary length.

```
[x > 1, x > 3, x > 5], minimal set: [x > 1]
```

Is the solution to just maintain the current minimum and maximum and then iterate through the comparator list? Is there a more optimal way from compiler theory to parse the values?

Comment: Group by `>` and `<` comparisons and take the `max` of `>` and `min` of `<`?

Comment: Aren't all of your examples wrong? Seems like the signs are in the wrong direction

Comment: @tobias_k - why bother with grouping? a simple iteration is enough

Comment: @Amit Sure, just wanted to make clear of what elements to take the min and of which the max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate the list of comparisons and for each variable memorize the upper and lower bounds. Here's a very straight-forward implementation in Python.

```
def find_bounds(lst):
    bounds = {}
    for var, op, val in map(str.split, lst):
        if var not in bounds: bounds[var] = [float("-inf"), float("+inf")]
        if op == ">":
            bounds[var][0] = max(bounds[var][0], float(val))
        if op == "<":
            bounds[var][1] = min(bounds[var][1], float(val))
    return bounds
```

Examples:

```
>>> find_bounds(["x > 3", "x < 6", "x > 4", "x < 9"])
{'x': [4.0, 6.0]}
>>> find_bounds(["x > 5", "x < 1", "x < 10"])
{'x': [5.0, 1.0]}
>>> find_bounds(["x > 3", "x < 9", "y > 3"])
{'x': [3.0, 9.0], 'y': [3.0, inf]}
```

Next, you can supplement that with a function that turns those bounds back into comparisons:

```
def bounds_to_comparisons(bounds):
    result = []
    for var in bounds:
        lower, upper = bounds[var]
        if lower < upper:
            if lower != float("-inf"):
                result.append("%s > %f" % (var, lower))
            if upper != float("+inf"):
                result.append("%s < %f" % (var, upper))
        else:
            result.append("%s undefined" % var)
    return result
```

Examples:

```
>>> bounds_to_comparisons({'x': [4.0, 6.0]})
['x > 4.00', 'x < 6.00']
>>> bounds_to_comparisons({'x': [5.0, 1.0]})
['x undefined']
>>> bounds_to_comparisons({'y': [3.0, inf], 'x': [3.0, 9.0]})
['y > 3.00', 'x > 3.00', 'x < 9.00']
```

Answer (score 1):

Other then aborting early as soon as an undefined result of found, there's no optimization to be made. All entries must be processed and each entry is only processed once.